# How to correctly animate change of size of a paged UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have an iPad app similar to the iPad Keynote with a narrow overview on the left and a paged `UICollectionView` of my "slides" on the right. The collection view is using the default FlowLayout.  Some of these slides are standard PDFs and some are embedded `UIViewController`s that have been scaled (with a `CGAffineTransform`) and embedded in the cell.  I'd like to smoothly animate the overview sidebar offscreen and zoom the current page cell to fullscreen.  The collection view should allow paged swiping at whatever size.  I'm using storyboards and autolayout.

I think I need to simultaneously animate about three things:

- The collection view constraints (to the sidebar) to enlarge/shrink it
- The flow layout's `sizeForItemAt:` value
- The `CGAffineTransform` on the embedded view controller.

I have some pieces working (a single embedded View Controller "slide" that scales correctly) but cannot get the collectionView/cell resize dance to work correctly.  The cell resize animation is jerky, or ends up with the wrong offset, or works for the leftmost cell but not for other cells.

I've tried most of the suggestions in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13780153/2431627) but with no convincing success.  I can't believe it's impossible but at this point I'm considering the smoke and mirrors approach of animating a static slide and hiding it after the animation completes.  The attached video - ignoring the glitches - illustrates the kind of effect I'm after:

[image]

It's worth noting, on close inspection, that Keynote cheats somewhat when it comes to swiping between slides in edit mode, and manually manages the next slide sliding onscreen, so probably doesn't use a `UICollectionView`.

Has anyone done anything similar, or have any suggestions for things to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.  There's a proof-of-concept GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/robinmacharg/CollectionViewResizingDemo).

There are a few moving parts:

- There are two pieces of UIView scaling code.  I suspect these could be combined with suitable delegate references as the nested view controllers are embedded.  The first piece scales (statically) correctly when the Collection View cell is created.  The second is an animated scale/translate when the sidebar size is changed.
- I added a FlowLayout subclass to remove flicker as the collection's layout is invalidated during scaling.
- The sidebar-related transform in the top-level VC uses most of the tricks in the book - `invalidateLayout()`, `performBatchUpdates(...)`, `layoutIfNeeded()` etc. as well as animating the `contentOffset` to the correct value.  Some manual tracking of the correct page/slide is required.
- There's still  a slight flicker occasionally at the start of resizing.  This may not be an issue with my particular colour-scheme which will be black on dark gray.  Bonus points if anyone can suggest how to track this down or alleviate it.